# Fixed point problem

Tags: analysis

If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continue function , there is $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $M>0$ satisfied:
$$|f^{(n)}(a)|\le M,\forall n\in N^+$$when $f^{(n)}=f\circ f\circ ... \circ f$( n times) ,prove that f has a fixed point

Comment: You might assume not and then: (i) Can you explain why we have either $f(x)>x$ for all $x$, or $f(x)<x$ for all $x$? (ii) Then, if you assume $f(x)>x$ for all $x$, can you reach a contradiction?

Comment: @Michael I see :P thanks